# Can I link an unregistered eFiling to a new account?

Tags: provisional-application, uspto, pair

I made an eFiling for a provisional patent application while unregistered. Can I now register myself and link that filing to my USPTO account? I have found that it would be useful to have an account to make a minor change to the filing.

Comment: Have you considered calling the USPTO to ask? It may be a situation where their support team might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In a USPTO pdf it states -

"Once you have your Customer Number, you must also associate your current patent
applications with it. . . . 
- Download and complete the Customer Number Upload Spreadsheet

To get more information and to download this form you can go to [Electronic Business Center](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/applying-online/getting-started-new-users). People at the EBC are very helpful for this type of question. 571-272-4100. They are available by phone from **6:00 a.m. to 12:00 midnight**, Eastern Time, Monday through Friday